# Changing the height ordering of widgets in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

In my app I have added a `UIView` as a new subView, however it covers up a `UISegmentedControl`. I was wondering if there's a way to move the `UISegmentedControl` back on top so its fully visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the [docs for UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) you'll find that there are several options:

- `-insertSubview:belowSubview:`
- `-insertSubview:atIndex:`
- `-bringSubviewToFront:`
- `-exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:`

Also, take a look at [View Architecture Fundamentals](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW9) for an overview of how views relate to each other.